# JQuery edit div from main file with loaded file script

Tags: jquery, html, styles, load, show

i want to show a div that's in my main file.

```
<html>
<body>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $( "#load_div" ).load( "/resources/load.php" );
    });
   </script>
   <div id="load_div"></div>
   <div id="change" style="display:none;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is in my loaded life:

```
<html>
<body>
   <script>
      $("#change").show();
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you check the browser console?

Comment: yes nothing special, it dont give any errors or info

Comment: You need to include jQuery too: `<html>
<head>   <script src="jquery.js"></script><script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $( "#load_div" ).load( "/resources/load.php" );
    });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="load_div"></div>
   <div id="change" style="display:none;"></div>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Try to set the script below the divs in your code

Comment: seems you have not called jQuery library, or the load.php what you are trying to load is not in the correct path as you have mentioned in your piece of code.

Comment: it doesn't change anything and i also included jquery

Comment: n1 its working, just put script under change div! thX! :D

Comment: or the document.ready in the head. Feel free to delete

Comment: @VeloFX  when people answers you question. you need to check and marked+up-vote the correct answer. I saw that you asked a lot of question but you didn't mark anyone answer.